# Drupal 7 How to find Nodes, tagged with Broken Taxonomies?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, database

In Drupal 7, some Taxonomy Terms were deleted (by force from direct DB Query, for some reason). So some Nodes left remained by still tagging this deleted Taxo Terms. Then the problem is arising at the Site Indexing stage. The process is getting broken.

So i believe i need to find the `Nodes` which are tagging to these no longer existing/broken `Taxonomy Terms`, to un-tag those.

- Which is the best way to do it?
- What will be the best Query for it?

Thanks.

Comment: I notice you also have 14 question, but have only accepted two answers.  I've answered your question anyway because I am a stand-up guy and I've found it to be similar to a problem I've had a couple of times ;-)  You might want to evaluate some of your previous questions though and accept some answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Just as an FYI, even if the terms had been deleted properly, the references still would have been broken (see [Database records not deleted for Term Reference Fields after Term is Deleted](http://drupal.org/node/1281114)).

Either way, to answer your question, you could use use super useful [Taxonomy Orphanage](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_orphanage) module.

> This module provides interfaces (drush, cron, admin form) for removing
>   orphaned taxonomy term references from entities.

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomy Term data is saved in 'taxonomy_term_data' table. And when you add a field e.g. Article Category (machine name - field_category) in your Article Content Type which is of type Term Reference to say Category Vocabulary then system creates a table like 'field_data_field_category'.

Now after knowing your table name for your custom field, you can execute a query which will give you Nodes which are tagging to these no longer existing/broken Taxonomy Terms,

```
SELECT f.* FROM field_data_field_category f left join taxonomy_term_data t on f.field_category_tid = t.tid WHERE t.tid is null;
```

Here you just need to specify your table/field name.

Comment: Huhh, sound interesting but, do i need to run for everrrrrrry field? I have more then 100 fields @_@

Comment: you can store all the fields required in PHP array